# RSS in a Rails app giving error: attribute <url> is missing in tag <source>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rss

I am trying to get the Washington Post Politics RSS feed to display in my Rails app.

```
wp_url = 'http://feeds.washingtonpost.com/rss/politics'
open(wp_url) do |rss|
  @wp_feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
end
```

With that code, I am getting the error:

```
attribute <url> is missing in tag <source>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs when the external feed is invalid.
In this case, the RSS does not contain the required `url` attribute for the `<source>` element.

According to the [RSS 2.0 specs for the `<source>` element](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#ltsourcegtSubelementOfLtitemgt),

> `<source>` is an optional sub-element of `<item>`.
>
> Its value is the name of the RSS channel that the item came from, derived from its . It has one required attribute, `url`, which links to the XMLization of the source.
>
> `<source url="http://www.tomalak.org/links2.xml">Tomalak's Realm</source>`
>
> The purpose of this element is to propagate credit for links, to publicize the sources of news items. It can be used in the Post command of an aggregator. It should be generated automatically when forwarding an item from an aggregator to a weblog authoring tool.

The [RSS class as mentioned in Ruby 1.9.3 doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rss/rdoc/RSS/Parser.html) explains its `parse` method with these default parameters:

```
parse(rss, do_validate=true, ignore_unknown_element=true, parser_class=default_parser)
```

So if you want to ignore such validation errors, pass `false` as the second parameter and you'll be reading external RSS feeds with this:

```
require 'rss'
wp_url = open('http://feeds.washingtonpost.com/rss/politics').read
@wp_rss = RSS::Parser.parse(wp_url, false)
```